# Clipping Basemap with ASCII file using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, clip

I work with ArcGIS 10 and I add a basemap layer from the ArcGIS Online but I just want the continent coverage to my map, and the area that I wanted I have an ascii file, like a grid.

How can I cut of the ocean part?

Is it the "Clip" function the better option?

Is there a script for python for this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can't clip the basemap layer from the ArcGIS online. It's pre-generated images from underlying data that is not available to the public.

What I think you want is some data that shows just the continent that you are interested in. ArcGIS comes with sample data. You might find continent data in there. You also could probably find a shapefile or file gdb on the internet that contains just continent outlines.

As far as web services, that you could add into ArcMap, take a look at these.. (found these searching in ArcGIS online)

Here is a feature service of continents without oceans:
http://services.arcgis.com/BG6nSlhZSAWtExvp/arcgis/rest/services/Continents/FeatureServer

Here is a shaded relief to display with continents if you desire:
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer
More info here..
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9c5370d0b54f4de1b48a3792d7377ff2